# Throwing exception in method or the calling method

Tags: php, oop, exception, stack-trace

Sorry for the vague title.

I am wondering what is the best to do in a scenario like this:

```
$template = $loader->load('file');

if (!$template) {
    throw new \Exception('my custom exception');
}
```

Would it be better to keep it like this, or actually throw the exception in the `$loader->loader()` method?

I guess if you actually do encounter an exception that was thrown like in  the example, you would always click through the method where the exception was thrown anyways. So there would be no real reason for the exception to be higher up the stack trace.

Thoughts on this? Why would you catch the exception higher up the stack trace when you could have the method actually implement the exception?

Comment: It depends on the situation. If it would be file not found exception for example, it should be thrown inside the load method. If it concerns the outer scope it should be thrown in outer scope etc.

Comment: @patryk-uszynski True, but the line is kind of blurry. I mean when would it 'cornern the outer scope'. Because in both cases the outer scope is involved. I guess there is no clear-cut answer to this. Still I posted because I would like people's thoughts on this. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score -1):

My opinion is method must comply with the contract or die.
Every time you get an object as an input you must check whether it is NULL or a valid object reference. If you forget to check, a `NullPointerException` may break execution in runtime. Thus, your logic becomes polluted with multiple checks and if/then/else forks as you described above.

Why null is bad you can read [there](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/13/why-null-is-bad.html)